# MySQL ON UPDATE CASCADE with self-referencing

Tags: mysql, cascade

> According to
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>
> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET
>   NULL recurses to update the same table
>   it has *previously* updated during the
>   cascade, it acts like RESTRICT

My reading of this means that at least one cascading update should be allowed, and thereafter any *further* updates should be RESTRICTed. This is not the case with a self-referencing table. No updates are done, only this error is given:

`ERROR 1451 (23000) at line 1: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('temp'.'tableA', CONSTRAINT 'FK5E61277C3139BCA6' FOREIGN KEY ('foreign_key_id') REFERENCES 'tableA' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

Do you agree with this? Why is this the case?

Comment: sorry, but the end of the paragraph in that page explains it:
QUOTE:
"This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations."

Comment: @RephaelHerjcovici, yes, I saw that, but the question is whether you think this should be the expected behaviour, and why?

Comment: im sorry to be an ass, but it sure is expected if it is contained in the documentation.....
also, further down the text:
QUOTE:
"This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates."

Comment: i am wondering, do you need a solution for that?
or just learning about the error ?

Comment: @RephaelHerjcovici: I wanted to increment every KEY in my whole db by say 10000000 using CASCADING to automatically update every FK reference, but this (clearly) fails on self-referencing tables.
So, my thoughts are that if one cascade-pass is done there should be no problems, but as soon as a second update is done it should be restricted to prevent the infinite loop, and this is how I understand that paragraph I posted. Agree?